# JavaFX to Android

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, javafx-8, gradlew

I'm currently developing a JavaFX application and I want to deploy it onto the  Android platform.
Therefore, I followed this tutorial: [Building and Deploying Android Apps Using JavaFX](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Building-JavaFX-Android-Apps)

I'm using the Ensemble sample.
After executing the convertJavaFXToAndroid.bat, I got the following error:

```
 Execution failed for task ':androidCreateProject'
 A problem occured starting process 'command' android.bat.
```

Please help!

Comment: Run it in debug mode or at least info mode and investigate the output.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it! Edited the gradle.build and I changed the location of android.bat. That's it!